# Subscribe Methods return undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, api, ionic-framework

```
 get() {
    const obs = this.http.get(this.url);
    obs.subscribe((response) => {this.sakla = response; 
  });

 constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation,public http: HttpClient) {

 }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.get(); 
    console.log(this.sakla); //x line 
 }
```

That get() function is compelete after ngOnInit(). So x line gives undefined because in ngoninit didn't compeletly execute this.get() function. What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me mark it in steps to clarify your query :

```
get(){
// step 3
    const obs = this.http.get(this.url);
    obs.subscribe((response) => {
      // stpe 5
      this.sakla = response; 
    });

constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation,public http: HttpClient) { // step 1  }

ngOnInit(){
// step 2
    this.get(); 
// step 4
    console.log(this.sakla); //x line
 }
```

Reason it being undefined is "http.get()" is asynchronous in nature that is, till the time you will receive response, your code will already execute "console.log()" thus, you are getting undefined.

To rectify the same, following things can be done :

a) return observable from get method and subscribe in ngOnit method

b) use async-await in get method definition as well as in this.get() call

c) convert it to promise and resolve promise when received response.

d) Simply, log inside subscribe method only

Cheers (y)

Answer (score 1):

Your `get` function is an asynchronous one. The browser will start the HTTP request and immediately after will execute the console.log.

Move the console.log inside your subscribe handler to see the results.

```
get() {
    const obs = this.http.get(this.url);

    obs.subscribe((response) => {
        this.sakla = response;

        console.log(this.sakla); //x line
    });

constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation,public http: HttpClient) {}


ngOnInit(){
    this.get();
}
```